# Javascript regexp replace sub-word

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript regexp replace text below:

```
i love #HTC & #HTC-One
```

to

```
i love <a href="#/topic/HTC">#HTC</a> & <a href="#/topic/HTC-One">HTC-One</a>
```

Comment: To increase you chance to get an answer you should provide some information about what you have tried this far to solve the problem. As it is now you haven't shown any attempt to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = "i love #HTC & #HTC-One".replace(
    /#([\w-]+)/g,
    '<a href="#/topic/$1">#$1</a>');
```

The regex looks for words that start with # alpha numeric and -.

The word without the # is enclosed in parenthesis to make it a capturing group.

The capturing group is referenced in the replacement with $1